# Bring back the old password of Gmail

Tags: email, gmail

I want to change my Gmail Password with the old one that i used before. Anybody know how i can do it? Because Google doesn't allow me to use the old password.

Comment: GmaIl does not allow you to reset your password to one that used before, its a standard security procedure to avoid account misuse

Answer (score 0):

Change your password 5 or 10 times in a row, and then change it back to the one you want. Most password managers only keep a history of the last 5 or 10 changes (particularly banks). As the comment on the question is right, password security policies are there to protect you, the user from unauthorized access.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've not tried it on Google, but other sites it works like a charm.